# error: Uncaught (in promise) NotFound: Failed to spawn 'start': program not found

Tags: deno, deno-deploy

I'm running [`deployctl deploy`](https://docs.deno.com/deploy/manual/deployctl) and here is the result:

```
PS D:\QC supplements\Code\Apps\trankyweb> deployctl deploy --project=c5w-tran-ky --entrypoint="./ThanhPhan BoTro/web/main.ts"
i Using config file 'D:\QC supplements\Code\Apps\trankyweb\deno.json'
i Provisioning a new access token...
i Authorization URL: https://dash.deno.com/signin/cli?claim_challenge=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
error: Uncaught (in promise) NotFound: Failed to spawn 'start': program not found
      .spawn()
       ^
    at spawnChildInner (ext:runtime/40_process.js:173:17)
    at spawnChild (ext:runtime/40_process.js:194:10)
    at Command.spawn (ext:runtime/40_process.js:462:12)
    at provision (https://deno.land/x/deploy@1.10.3/src/utils/access_token.ts:68:8)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:182:7)
    at async Object.provision (https://deno.land/x/deploy@1.10.3/src/utils/access_token.ts:14:19)
    at async API.#request (https://deno.land/x/deploy@1.10.3/src/utils/api.ts:103:44)
    at async API.#requestJson (https://deno.land/x/deploy@1.10.3/src/utils/api.ts:127:17)
    at async API.getProject (https://deno.land/x/deploy@1.10.3/src/utils/api.ts:202:14)
    at async deploy (https://deno.land/x/deploy@1.10.3/src/subcommands/deploy.ts:188:17)
```

Why does this happen? I have no idea how to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: [Version 1.10.4](https://github.com/denoland/deployctl/releases/tag/1.10.4) had a fix for this bug and improved feedback

---

I had the same problem, refreshing my token worked. Here's the [official Doc about how to do it](https://docs.deno.com/deploy/manual/#create-and-export-a-deploy-access-token)